# check if image exists on intranet

Tags: c#, .net, intranet

Im using the answer in this question [Test to see if an image exists in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192085/test-to-see-if-an-image-exists-in-c-sharp) to find out if images exists.

However I am getting an exception with error: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

The images are on our sharepoint intranet, so how can i test to see if the images do exists?

Thanks

Comment: As I remember the IIS user has no privileges on the network by default.

Comment: request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);

Comment: @L.B - that worked, I'll mark as answer if you add it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);`