# C# Store app check if picture in URL is available

Tags: c#, url, windows-store-apps

I am making a C# store app which contains pictures. I get the pictures from a website for example: http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/6810d91caff032b202c50701dd3af745?d=identicon&r=PG

I have 2 images, 1 is an image of the actual product. and 1 image is an image that there is no image available. Now i want to check if there is a picture behind the given URL, and if there is not, i want to load the image that there is no image available.

i got an object product which contains itemnumber, description and an imagepath. At this point i simply do this.

```
var url = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/6810d91caff032b202c50701dd3af745?d=identicon&r=PG";
Product p = new product (123, "productdescription", url);
```

if (url //if no results given){ p.url = imgpath2} // filepath with no image available picture

How can I make a simple check if the given url contains a picture, or will give me a "webpage not available"/ no content available error? thanks in advance.

edit: Note* i'm working with visual studio 2013, and I am building a C# store app.

Comment: What does the Product constructor look like?

Answer (score 3):

No need to download the entire image, just use HEAD:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("url");
request.Method = "HEAD";

bool exists;
try
{
    request.GetResponse();
    exists = true;
}
catch
{
   exists = false;
}
```

For more info, you can check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/192141/3232673) for help with your issue:

---

**[Update: If you want to make the call asynchronously...]**

```
// Initialize your product with the 'blank' image
Product p = new Product(123, "productdescription", imgpath2);

// Initialize the request
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("url");
request.Method = "HEAD";

// Get the response async
Task<WebResponse> response = request.GetResponseAsync();

// Get the response async
response.AsAsyncAction().Completed += (a, b) =>
    {
        // Assign the proper image, if exists, when the task is completed
        p.URL = url;
    };
```

Comment: I see how this can work. But the problem is I am making a C# store app. The only operation available for me is request.GetResponsAsync(); which requires me to make the method async. 

Long story short: When i enter an invalid webadres, it will provide me with the following error: A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The remote name could not be resolved

Comment: You can make a sync call this way: WebResponse response = request.GetResponseAsync().Result;

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    var url = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/6810d91caff032b202c50701dd3af745?d=identicon&r=PG";
    if(File.Exists(url)){
         Product p = new product (123, "productdescription", url);
    }
    else{
         Product p = new product (123, "productdescription", imgpath2);
    }
```

If the file exists it should return a true, if not it should return a false.

If you want to look at how to figure out how to find out if a url gives you any reponse, you can also take a look at this previous topic:
[C# How can I check if a URL exists/is valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924679/c-sharp-how-can-i-check-if-a-url-exists-is-valid)